# Landing with Gusts

Tags: landing, crosswind

When landing in gusty conditions, many people use half flaps to come in at a higher speed. If you were to use full flaps and a normal approach speed, could a strong gust cause the plane to pitch up violently due to the fact that lift has been increased?

My instructor said you could exceed critical the AOA, is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Though an accurate answer would rely on knowing what aircraft type you are referring to, I think in general you are also getting a little confused with the idea of lift and pitch. Gusty conditions can cause sudden rises and falls, due to varying relative airflow over the wing. But such a rise does not necessarily mean an increase in pitch, rather the whole aircraft rising, like a ballooning effect*. If the wind dies down after a gust, a sinking down might occur.

*<sub>The same effect experienced when deploying the flaps - increasing the amount of flap used</sub>

A higher approach speed with lower flaps increases controllability. The higher speed itself gives increased control authority for the ailerons, elevators and rudders. The lower flap setting reduces sensitivity to lift changes during the gusts.

With this AOA issue you refer to, I wonder if your instructor was referring to a go-around. In case a go-around is necessary, a reduced flap setting allows for a more efficient transition to climb configuration. The aircraft already being at a higher speed reduces the time and distance needed to accelerate to the go-around speed, enhancing safety.